# CSS Positioning to parent's corner

Tags: css

how to position a div element so that it shows at the top left corner, on top of all the content of the parent div, but at the same time its width does not extened more than its parents width?

Thanking you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution to it by myself. To make the child div appear on the top right corner of the parent div i set its position to absolute and top and left to 0. I solved the width problem by dynamically setting the child's width to the parent's width using jquery.

Note: the parent element's position should be set to relative for this to work on firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the width, it depends how much content you have - can you set a static width on the element?

Regarding the positioning, you need to set

```
position:relative
```

on the parent, then add:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

on the child.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure...

if you position this item with:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

And the patent Div must have

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Live preview: http://jsfiddle.net/PA6JZ/

```css
#parent { position: relative; }
#child { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Boom</div>
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```